# How to change ol Tag start value in page load using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

How to change ol Tag value in page load using asp.net c#, below is my ol tag code.

```
<ol class="que-no-left" start="1" id="Question1" runat="server">
    <li>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Below page load i want to change start value from 1 to 2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attributes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Question1.Attributes.Add("start", "2");
    }
}
```

If you want to read them

```
foreach(var key in Question1.Attributes.Keys)
{
    Label1.Text += string.Format("{0}: {1}<br>", key, Question1.Attributes[key.ToString()]);
}
```